# How to call an interval that has equal start and end point?

Tags: terminology

For instance let's say that I have a `Interval` class, that has `startPoint` and `endPoint` fields, getter and setter methods (functions) accordingly. and I need to create a method that returns boolean value of `startPoint == endPoint`. And have a question regarding naming point. How to call this method? `isEmpty()` or `isZeroLength()`. I am beginner self-educated programmer, and truly I am not so good in math, so I don't know how it is called in math (empty interval or an interval with zero length), so that I use that determination.

Comment: This might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Classification_of_intervals

Comment: So an interval that has equal starting and ending point, could be called empty interval as an empty set. You were right it helped. Thanks

Comment: Is such interval open or closed? I.e. does it contain no points $a < x < a$ or exactly one point $a \leq x \leq a$? I'd call it empty interval or singleton interval, accordingly.

Comment: It is closed, i.e. both points are inclusive.

Comment: Your question is, essentially, "What do mathematicians call intervals of zero length?" That doesn't seem to be a question about computer science.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes, and I got the answer. It is rather to call empty interval

Comment: I'd call it a *degenerate* interval.

Comment: @pyramidPeak No, an empty interval would be one that contains no points. Yours contains a single point.

Comment: @DavidRicherby But according to this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Classification_of_intervals even an interval has one point it will be an empty one.

Comment: That link specifies ​ a < b . ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @DavidRicherby Oh, you are right. I missed that probably

Comment: I would call $[3,3]$ a singleton interval, and $[3,3)=(3,3)=(3,3]=[3,2]$ an empty interval. Degenerate, as Yuval suggests, is indeed a good name to refer to any of these one-point or zero-points intervals. Zero-length would also be clear, I think.